# Confusion about proof of Unit Balls are not compact in Infinite Dimensional Normed Spaces with Riesz's Lemma

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

We can construct a sequence such that $\|x_n-x_m\|\gt 1/2$ via using Riesz's Lemma. It's not Cauchy sequence and thus it's not a convergent sequence.

My question : In my notes "since the sequence is not convergent, it doesn't have a convergent subsequence" has been written. But when $(-1)^n$ is not convergent, its subsequence is $(-1)^{2n}$ is convergent to $1$. How can we say it doesn't have a convergent subsequence? Where am I wrong, I couldn't realize. Thanks a lot

Comment: I wouldn't say "since the sequence is not convergent, it doesn't have a convergent subsequence".  Rather, I would say "by construction, this sequence has no convergent subsequence".

Comment: @Aweygan thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that looks like an error in the notes.

The conclusion does hold, but for different reasons. The fact $\|x_n-x_m\|>\frac 12$ means that *no subsequence can be Cauchy*, and since convergent sequences are always Cauchy, this means that no subsequence is convergent either.

Comment: Thank you sir :) How can I show this implication?